# Prove in complexity theory

Tags: computational-complexity

Given a language A, which is in NP and also not NP-complete, I have to prove that P != NP.

[Note: A is not trivial]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If A is in NP but not NP-complete, that means it's not NP-hard. Now assume P = NP and show that every nontrivial language in NP is NP-hard under that assumption.

(The statement even holds for any nontrivial language at all.)

Comment: I stuck at this point, that's the reason I wrote this question.

Comment: If P = NP, what can you solve with the reduction you need for an NP-hardness proof?

Comment: realy have no idea...

Comment: What kind of algorithm is the reduction allowed to be?

Comment: Still don't get it

Comment: Maybe post what your understanding of NP-hardness is?

Comment: Language B is NP-hard if for all A in NP, there's a polinomial reduction from A to B

Comment: Alright, now if P = NP, what can your reduction from A to B solve for $A \in $ NP?

Comment: But we don't know that the reduction exists, since A is not NP-hard

Comment: The comment should've been about $B,C \in$ NP to avoid confusion. Assume P = NP; can you then reduce $B$ to $C$ in deterministic polynomial time? How?

Comment: How can I do such reduction?

Comment: I realy don't understand what you're trying to tell me.
Can you please give me a better hint? (or solution because It's the first time I try to solve such question).

Comment: I could, but that's not the purpose of exercise; since this is homework, I expect you will be told the solution in due time, so not getting an answer now shouldn't deprive you of getting a solution at all. When I get stuck, I usually lean back, forget about it for today, mull it over and try again tomorrow.

Comment: I understand you, but I think that there's something I'm missing here, and if I see a given proof now, I'll be able to solve by myself in future homeworks.